# Make button close a div (using Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm using a plug-in (PopUp Maker) to create a pop-up landing page. Inside it I have a button (made by me) that should close this pop-up.

I have no clue how to do it. I tried adding some javascript but is not working, and the thing is that I don't know if it's my code that isn't correct, Wordpress not reading my javascript file, or the plug in preventing me from doing it.

Any suggestions?

Here's the code I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close-button').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function(){
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Put an `alert` or a `console.log` in your code to check if your javasript is actually read.

Comment: It would help too, if you provided the relevant HTML associated with the problem.

Comment: If you're in the Chrome development window (Im sure other browsers can also do it) you can inspect the relevant button and see if there are any events associated with it. It should show a click event, and when you select it, it should show your code. If it's not there, your code is not executed correctly. Also, if you do see the event, you can place breakpoints in the development window (on lines of javascript code).

Comment: and try using jQuery(document).ready(function($) instead of $(document).ready(function()

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Native Javascript Solution to Close or open a Div by onclick.

```
function myFunction(){
if (document.getElementById('idofpopupdiv').style.display == "none") {
document.getElementById('idofpopupdiv').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('idofpopupdiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
} else {
document.getElementById('idofpopupdiv').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('idofpopupdiv').style.visibility = 'none';}}
```

and your button should have an onclick  event to call the function.

```
<button onclick="myFunction();">Button Name</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace #idofpopupdiv with the id of your popup div or a classname

```
$(function() {
    $('.close-button').click(function() {
        $('#idofpopupdiv').fadeOut('slow', function () {

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How can you be sure this solves the problem. His code would actually fade out at least the button that was clicked. OP would surely mention this in his question - as he is not sure whether or not the code is even executed.

Comment: I can't be sure, but his code is assuming that the close button is a direct child of the popup he wishes to close

Comment: So if you're not sure, this is not a valid answer. Considering you do not have the comment privilege yet, you should get that first so you can put this as a comment next time (which would be helpful)